# Need to see where my ACL in RunDeck is failing in RunDeck 3.1.1

Tags: security, policy, rundeck

We are setting up a RunDeck site so that users can only see their own projects.  Within that structure I need to make users who are job viewers/job writers/job runners and project admins.  I have runners and project admins and viewers working.  However I can't seem to get the job writers to work.  I am using two acl files.  Whenever I login as the user I can't see the 'create job' button and when I navigate to rundeck/project/MY_PROJECT/job/create I get the error 'Not authorized to create New Job'  What am I missing?

This is the my_project_job_writer.acl

```
    ---
context:
  application: 'rundeck'
description: "project_job_writer"
for:
  project:
    - equals:
        name: 'MY_PROJECT'
      allow: [read]

  system:
    - match:
        name: '.*'
      allow: [read]
by:
  username: ['jack.hill','jill.hill']

---

context:
  project:
    - equals:
        name: 'MY_PROJECT'
description: "project_job_writer"
for:
  resource:
  - equals:
      kind: 'node'
    allow: [read,refresh]
  - equals:
      kind: job
    allow: [create, delete]
  - equals:
      kind: event
    allow: [read]
  job:
  - allow: [create,read,update,delete,run,kill]
    match:
      name: '.*'
  node:
  - allow: [read, run, refresh]
    match:
      nodename: '.*'
by:
  username: ['jack.hill','jill.hill']
```

This is the system-job_writer.acl

```
description: Allow groups to list projects
context:
  application: 'rundeck'
for:
  project:
    - equals:
        name: 'Default'
      allow: [read]
  system:
    - match:
        name: '.*'
      allow: [read]
by:
  group: job_writer

---

description: Global write permissions to job_writer role
context:
  project: '.*'
for:
  resource:
  - equals:
      kind: 'node'
    allow: [read,refresh]
  - equals:
      kind: job
    allow: [create, delete]
  - equals:
      kind: event
    allow: [read]
  job:
  - allow: [create,read,update,delete,run,kill]
    match:
      name: '.*'
  node:
  - allow: [read, run, refresh]
    match:
      nodename: '.*'
by:
  group: job_writer
```

And these are the entries in realm.properties

```
jack.hill:password,user,job_writer
jill.hill:password,user,job_writer
```

Answer (score 1):

So, the old IT solve worked.  I just restarted the apache server it was running on and 'bam' it worked. well that was a hour wasted, lol.  For anyone wanting to use this acl policy it comes in handy.

Comment: Thank you SO much. This seems to still be an issue on 3.3.7. I could create a project but not see the list of projects without restarting.